# Effectiveness of Neale's Brewing Supplies no rinse sanitizer

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer, starsan

What Ph level does [Neale's Brewing Supplies sanitizer](https://www.nealesbrewingsupplies.co.uk/sterilisers-cleaners-chemicals/nbs-no-rinse-sanitiser-250ml/prod_945.html) remain effective to?

It has a similar ingredient list to starsan, which is listed to be effective so long as the pH of the solution is 3 or lower.

I live in an area of hard water and want to check my sanitization is up to scratch...

Also generally, how effective is this compared to StarSan? StarSan seems to be a lot more popular on the internet, but not sure if this is just because of a skew towards homebrewers in the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pH below 3.0 is a recognized threshold condition needed to rupture cell walls of most bacteria.

Regardless of the product brand 3.0 pH would be the number to keep it below.